# Fuzzy Search History: Show History Keeping The Lines Intact For Multi-Line Commands

Tags: shell-script, zsh, command-history, zle

I am working on a zsh widget to fuzzy search history.

```
skim-history() {
  origquery=${BUFFER}
  output=$(history -1 1 | sd '^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*' '' | sk --tac --no-sort --exact)

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    BUFFER=$output
  else
    BUFFER=$origquery
  fi

  CURSOR=$#BUFFER
}

zle     -N   skim-history
bindkey '^R' skim-history
```

In `history -1 1 | sd '^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*' '' | sk --tac --no-sort --exact`, [sd](https://github.com/chmln/sd) is used instead of sed, which just removes numbers from the beginning. [sk](https://github.com/lotabout/skim) is an alternative for fzf.

This widget works pretty well except multi-line commands.

For example: it shows

[image]

like:

[image]

So, it replace newline with `\n`. This is not something i want.

The command looks like the following in `.zsh_history` file:

```
: 1657176206:0;function brcd() {\
 cd $(broot --only-folders --hidden --cmd "$1;:pp")\
}\
```

What I found is !NUM get the history in correct format.

[image]

what changes do I need to make on my widget? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I replaced `history -1 1 | sd '^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*' ''` with `fc -ln 1 -1`.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, you could use [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) which provides a "fuzzy search history".

Comment: Related: [How to send output to next input line?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/706848)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP Here. The solution is:

```
skim-history() {
  num=$(fc -l 1 -1 | sk --tac --no-sort --exact | rg -o '^[ ]*([0-9]*)[ ]*' -r '$1')

  if [ -n "$num" ]; then
      zle vi-fetch-history -n $num
  fi
}

zle     -N   skim-history
bindkey '^R' skim-history
```